# Invalid syntax error after printing formatted string

Tags: python

```
def display_line(country_name, region_name, happiness_score):
    print("{:24s}{:<32s}{:<17.2f}".format(country_name, region_name, happiness_score)

def main():
```

I don't understand why I am experiencing an invalid syntax error on the line containing "def main()". I thought that my string formatting line is correct, no? Could this error be caused by something beyond these lines of code?

Error traceback message:

> runfile('/Users/brandononeil/Documents/SS18proj05.py', wdir='/Users/brandononeil/Documents')
>     File "/Users/brandononeil/Documents/SS18proj05.py", line 37
>       def main():
>         ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your print statement lacks a closing `)`.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a bracket at the end:

```
def display_line(country_name, region_name, happiness_score):
    print("{:24s}{:<32s}{:<17.2f}".format(country_name, region_name, happiness_score))
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the print function!

```
print("{:24s}{:<32s}{:<17.2f}".format(country_name, region_name, happiness_score))
```